# How to Highlight an item in Recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to highlight an item in recycler view and also when the second item is clicked the first one should be unhighlighted

Here is the code that I have tried:

```html
    private var selectedItem=-1
    
        if (selectedItem==position){
            holder.binding.songName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B57DF0"))
            holder.binding.root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4C3A71"))
        }
             holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener()
        {
            options.itemClicked(songsListAdapter[position],position)

            val previousItem=selectedItem
            selectedItem=position

            notifyItemChanged(previousItem)
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
```

Comment: Have you kept the else part of this if (selectedItem==position){
            holder.binding.songName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B57DF0"))
            holder.binding.root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4C3A71"))
        }